# MySQL: Optimize table with lots of columns

Tags: mysql, optimization, normalization

My user table has over 26 columns, is that normal? The db is already normalized to the 3rd level when this user table caught my eye. Is having 26 columns ok or is there some other optimization technique you use when designing your db that I should be doing?

**More:** What's meant by Partitioning your table?

Comment: Well, if you have to store 26 unique attributes of a user, there is nothing wrong with having 26 columns :) What I want to say: We can't tell something about it without knowing the context. But I think you can simply figure it out yourself just by going through each of the normalization steps.

Comment: Always post DDL when you're asking a question like this. Normalization is based on dependencies; normalization never asks "How many columns are there?".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there's nothing wrong with 26 columns but if they are rarely used then its different.

instead of using 26 columns, you take the one that you use less and group them using a serialize string.

change the field to a text field and then in your code you can de-serialize them and use them. if you need to update, you update the array (from your code) and then serialize it and save it to the database.

Comment: What's the advantage of this approach? Those "rarely-used" (do you mean usually-NULL or rarely-queried?) columns aren't likely to impact your database's performance. But querying serialized data *will* be a PITA. :)

Comment: What you're saying is I can combine the values of fields of what I think will be the slowest moving columns. By grouping them you mean saving them as a string in PHP then putting that string to the db? I've never done this before...sounds cheezy.

Comment: i mean if you have for example: background color the value does not change often so you select + deserialize then use it. queyring serialize data is the same as a string but you simply have to serialize on inserts and reverse on read. PLUS: if you need to add more columns, you dont have to ALTER tables, you just add an KEY in the array and you are done

Comment: I'm new to MySQL. If anyone does this, won't this be a violation of the First Normal Form?

Comment: if you want to respect all the forms and be by the book, probably

Comment: As @djacobson says this seems to introduce unnecessary complexity for the sake of removing a few columns.

Comment: No part of normalization asks, "How often is this column used?"

Comment: This is a TERRIBLE recommendation - you can't validate data in the serialized field at the database level (data type, nullability), you can't index it, and if it turns up in the "where" clause, the performance will be poor.