# mysql table with 40+ columns

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, multiple-columns

I have 40+ columns in my table and i have to add few more fields like, current city, hometown, school, work, uni, collage..

These user data wil be pulled for many matching users who are mutual friends  (joining friend table with other user friend to see mutual friends) and who are not blocked and also who is not already friend with the user.

The above request is little complex, so i thought it would be good idea to put extra data in same user table to fast access, rather then adding more joins to the table, it will slow the query more down. but i wanted to get your suggestion on this

my friend told me to add the extra fields, which wont be searched on one field as serialized data.

**ERD Diagram:**

- My current table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMwxb.png
- If i join into more tables: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhAxE.png

**Some Suggestions**

1. nothing wrong with this table and columns
2. follow this approach [MySQL: Optimize table with lots of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271964/mysql-optimize-table-with-lots-of-columns) - which serialize extra fields into one field, which are not searchable's
3. create another table and put most of the data there. (this gets harder on joins, if i already have 3 or more tables to join to pull the records for users (ex. friends, user, check mutual friends)

Comment: Properly normalized table schema with refrential integrities will serve you better when using joins... :)

Comment: 40+ **ROWS** are different from your question title **40+ columns**... ;) As @NevilleK pointed out it depends becasue even a fully normalized  and perfectly referenced table could have 100+ columns to **describe that entity**..

Comment: @bonCodigo sorry i meant columns

Comment: I'd go with something similar to your 2nd ERD, for your own sanity: separate authentication from "profile" information. If necessary, build a structure that can handle 3rd party logins -- not necessarily the FB specific one you've got there. If anything is a good candidate for field-smashing serialization in your schema, it's probably 3rd party login objects, which can be variable, are often handled by 3rd party libs, and are often delivered as json or xml anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As usual - it depends.

Firstly, there is a [maximum number of columns MySQL can support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/column-count-limit.html), and you don't really want to get there.

Secondly, there is a performance impact when inserting or updating if you have lots of columns with an index (though I'm not sure if this matters on modern hardware).

Thirdly, large tables are often a dumping ground for all data that seems related to the core entity; this rapidly makes the design unclear. For instance, the design you present shows 3 different "status" type fields (status, is_admin, and fb_account_verified) - I suspect there's some business logic that should link those together (an admin must be a verified user, for instance), but your design doesn't support that.

This may or may not be a problem - it's more a conceptual, architecture/design question than a performance/will it work thing. However, in such cases, you may consider creating tables to reflect the related information about the account, even if it doesn't have a x-to-many relationship. So, you might create "user_profile", "user_credentials", "user_fb", "user_activity", all linked by user_id. 
This makes it neater, and if you have to add more facebook-related fields, they won't dangle at the end of the table. It won't make your database faster or more scalable, though. The cost of the joins is likely to be negligible.

Whatever you do, option 2 - serializing "rarely used fields" into a single text field - is a terrible idea. You can't validate the data (so dates could be invalid, numbers might be text, not-nulls might be missing), and any use in a "where" clause becomes very slow.

A popular alternative is "Entity/Attribute/Value" or "Key/Value" stores. This solution has some benefits - you can store your data in a relational database even if your schema changes or is unknown at design time. However, they also have drawbacks: it's hard to validate the data at the database level (data type and nullability), it's hard to make meaningful links to other tables using foreign key relationships, and querying the data can become very complicated - imagine finding all records where the status is 1 and the facebook_id is null and the registration date is greater than yesterday.

Given that you appear to know the schema of your data, I'd say "key/value" is not a good choice.

Comment: what do you think of key, value paired table. ex: user_info with following fields (id, key, value) key value will be field name and value is the value of the column.. this way, it can put all the fields new or old fields easily..

Comment: I've updated the answer - if you know the schema of your data, and it's not volatile, key/value is not a brilliant solution for most relational requirements.

Comment: i have created your suggestion erd and added to the above question, please check and i have also wrote the question in more detailed.

Comment: I'd say the 2 extra tables in your 2nd ERD makes sense; you might put "name" in the profile table, but other than that I think it's all pretty clear.

Comment: I might say serializing multiple fields into a single text field is *usually* the wrong solution. But, it isn't necessarily a "terrible" idea. In this case, it may be. But, in other cases, if those fields are highly variable and/or never candidates for indexing or joining, there's reasonable justification for it. I.e., session state, form state, objects with dynamic field names or labels, large objects with hundreds of properties, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would advice to run some tests. Try it both ways and benchmark it. Nobody will be able to give you a definitive answer because you have not shared your hardware configuration, sample data, sample queries, how you plan on using the data etc. Here is some information that you may want to consider.

**Use The Database as it was intended**

A relational database is designed specifically to handle data. Use it as such. When written correctly, joining data in a well written schema will perform well. You can use EXPLAIN to optimize queries. You can log SLOW queries and improve their performance. Databases have been around for years, if putting everything into a single table improved performance, don't you think that would be all the buzz on the internet and everyone would be doing it?

**Engine Types**

How will inserts be affected as the row count grows? Are you using MyISAM or InnoDB? You will most likely want to use InnoDB so you get row level locking and not table. Make sure you are using the correct Engine type for your tables. Get the information you need to understand the pros and cons of both. The wrong engine type can kill performance.

**Enhancing Performance using Partitions**

Find ways to enhance performance. For example, as your datasets grow you could partition the data. [Data partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html) will improve the performance of a large dataset by keeping slices of the data in separate partions allowing you to run queries on parts of large datasets instead of all of the information.

**Use correct column types**

Consider using UUID Primary Keys for portability and future growth. If you use proper column types, it will improve performance of your data.

**Do not serialize data**

Using serialized data is the worse way to go. When you use serialized fields, you are basically using the database as a file management system. It will save and retrieve the "file", but then your code will be responsible for unserializing, searching, sorting, etc. I just spent a year trying to unravel a mess like that. It's not what a database was intended to be used for. Anyone advising you to do that is not only giving you bad advice, they do not know what they are doing. There are very few circumstances where you would use serialized data in a database.

**Conclusion**

In the end, you have to make the final decision. Just make sure you are well informed and educated on the pros and cons of how you store data. The last piece of advice I would give is to find out what heavy users of mysql are doing. Do you think they store data in a single table? Or do they build a relational model and use it the way it was designed to be used?

When you say "I am going to put everything into a single table", you are saying that you know more about performance and can make better choices for optimization in your code than the team of developers that constantly work on MySQL to make it what it is today. Consider weighing your knowledge against the cumulative knowledge of the MySQL team and the DBAs, companies, and members of the database community who use it every day.

Comment: but what if one table needs 50+ columns, then what? we should devide them into different tables? i was checking vb-forum, it has over 70+ columns for user table.

Comment: Define needs. Who's to say it NEEDS to be that way? There are reasons / rationalizations for everything. But to say it NEEDS to be that way is still ultimately a choice in architecture and design. There is nothing forcing them to put the data in a single table with 70+ columns.

Answer (score 1):

At a certain point you should look at the "short row model", also know as entity-key-value stores,as well as the traditional "long row model".

If you look at the schema used by WordPress you will see that there is a table wp_posts with 23 columns and a related table wp_post_meta with 4 columns (meta_id, post_id, meta_key, meta_value).  The meta table is a "short row model" table that allows WordPress to have an infinite collection of attributes for a post.

Neither the "long row model" or the "short row model" is the best model, often the best choice is a combination of the two.  As @nevillek pointed out searching and validating "short row" is not easy, fetching data can involve pivoting which is annoyingly difficult in MySql and Oracle.

The "long row model" is easier to validate, relate and fetch, but it can be very inflexible and inefficient when the data is sparse.  Some rows may have only a few of the values non-null. Also you can't add new columns without modifying the schema, which could force a system outage, depending on your architecture.

I recently worked on a financial services system that had over 700 possible facts for each instrument, most had less than 20 facts. This could have been built by setting up dozens of tables, each for a particular asset class, or as a table with 700 columns, but we chose to use  a combination of a table with about 20 columns containing the most popular facts and a 4 column table which contained the other facts. This design was efficient but was difficult ot access, so we built a few table functions in PL/SQL to assist with this.

Answer (score 0):

I have a general comment for you,

Think about it: If you put anything more than 10-12 columns in a table even if it makes sense to put them in a table, I guess you are going to pay the price in the short term, long term and medium term.

Your 3 tables approach seems to be better than the 1 table approach, but consider making those into 5-6 tables rather than 3 tables because you still can.

Move `currently`, `currently_position`, `currently_link` from `user-table` and `work` from `user-profile` into a new table with your primary key called `USERWORKPROFILE`.

Move locale Information from `user-profile` to a newer `USERPROFILELOCALE` information because it is generic in nature.

And yes, all your generic attributes in all the tables should be `int` and not `varchar`.
For instance, City needs to move out to a new table called `LIST`_OF_CITIES with `cityid`.
And your attribute `city` should change from `varchar` to `int` and point to `cityid` in LIST_OF_`CITIES`.

Do not worry about performance issues; the more tables you have, better the performance, because you are actually handing out the performance to the database provider instead of taking it all in your own hands.

Comment: The comment about the more tables you have the better the performance is wrong, becuase the joins you have will make is slower when querying if the complexity increases.

Comment: ok i stand corrected. i was referring to more tables in a RELATIONAL Context rather than a standalone basis. for eg if u hv a user,city in one table the performance will b slower than having user,city-id in one table and city-id,city in another one and having referential integrity between them. in the latter case the database server holds pointers to the city table as opposed to the former case where it holds values. apart from that the database now has 2 indexes to work with.. im writing this comment purely based on advantages from a database server point of view.there r 3NF gains as well.

Comment: and about the 10-12 columns reason why i say this is because i feel 10-12 columns is the ideal number of columns u can display on a browser page for Create/Read/Update/Delete Functionality or Insert/Update/Delete Functionality depending on how u term it. if u put 40 columns or so in a table, the span of your page view from a browser/client point of view becomes considerably huge. i have nothing against clubbing all related data in one table but i would try my immense best to give the user who is viewing ur data a full view at one browser/client glimpse without a scroll..