# Best approach for mysql table with large number of columns

Tags: php, mysql, database-performance

Mysql tables.

```
phones
| ID | Name  //5-6 columns
Specifications
| ID |phone_id| ram | camera | price |network // 50 columns approx
```

Now my specification table has 50 columns so far, so I need a suggestion how to handle this sort of situation ? Do I need to create some other tables to split specifications table or can I continue with this?
I need a better suggestion for better speed and performance.

Comment: DB design is impossible to do without more info. At a glance I can see in one table you have column names that _appear_ like they could be split out, so I'd guess that you need to sit down and decide which columns would be more suited in separate tables. eg is "ram" and "price" really suited in the same table? Surely you have more than 1 product, as such  you would "_likely_" have a prices table with prices mapped to (eg) product_id from a products table with all product_id. Perhaps "specs" table with ram and other things. Hard to say for sure tho with the info you have given

Comment: thank you for the reply.

Comment: I have placed some basic columns like name,price,image in one table,and remaining in specification table.Can you please have a look at this link

http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_note8-8505.php

Comment: thank you very useful article. @DMishra

Comment: See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav

Answer (score 1):

> Dealing with more than 50+ columns will not be best approach-

1. Data-Base operation like insert, update, select could take time.
2. Its became difficult task to handle the data when you are dealing
   with  50+ columns in the table.

So I suggest do not continue with adding columns into the tables. [mysql-table-with-40-columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14231921/mysql-table-with-40-columns) could be usefull to solve your problems.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can have 1 main table with id, name, date and some more post specific stuff.
Then you could create 1 meta_table wich contains the id, main_id (this links to the post in your main table), meta_name (i.e.: price or color or dimensions), meta_value (i.e.: 125,95 or black or 150 x 50 x 8).
This way you can make as many column-like values stored into 1 table wich gets linked to 1 main table using an id.
This is the same concept as wordpress is using.

Otherwise you could also use something called serialized data/arrays into your main table, this is 1 column field with many array keys and their values.